# Subclipse and GitHub not working

Tags: eclipse, github, subclipse

I'm trying to use subclipse with github but i'm getting the following error when I try to commit

```
Filesystem has no item
svn: URL 'https://github.com/[name]/[repository]/[project]' non-existent in revision 3

mkdir --parents -m "Initial import." [https://github.com/[name]/[repository]/[project]]
    Merge conflict during commit
svn: MKCOL not allowed
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the latest Eclipse comes directly with [Egit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) (as opposed to [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/), which is a plugin you have to add to your Eclipse), it would be easier to use directly a git repo (through an [SVN import](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-from-subversion))

But if it isn't possible, then I would recommend following and testing first the workflow described in the [GitHub blog post "Collaborating on GitHub with Subversion"](https://github.com/blog/1178-collaborating-on-github-with-subversion).

And then adding in that test svn repo your svn revisions, in order to `svn commit` those revisions to GitHub (from an SVN repo where you already tested and managed to `svn commit` a few test revisions).

Comment: I'm going to stay with Google Code for now then.

Comment: @jonas but google code supports git repos (as well as svn repos) ;)

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using Google Code with SVN, but I would like to use GitHub with SVN. I thought it would be easier though.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is Git doesn't support empty folders and SVN does.  Actually I'm not sure, it may just be Github's implementation but I can tell you I had the same issue and just putting a dummy file with no content in each empty folder let me proceed.